# Primary key not a Measure in cube?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, ssas, cube, bids

I'm new to `SSAS`, so please bear with me.

I have two tables: `FactTest` and `DimLocation`.  I'm including the table schema, but in essence,  and `FactTest.LocationName` is foreign key to `DimLocation.LocationName` and `DimLocation.LocationName` is `primary key`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FactTest](
    [test_date] [date] NULL,
    [DOWNLOAD] [float] NULL,
    [LocationName] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]


GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FactTest]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_FactTest_DimLocation] FOREIGN KEY([LocationName])
REFERENCES [dbo].[DimLocation] ([LocationName])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FactTest] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_FactTest_DimLocation]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DimLocation](
    [LocationId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LocationName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DimLocation] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [LocationName] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

`DimLocation` looks like this:

```
LocationId      LocationName
1               Houston
2               San Antonio
3               Dallas
4               Austin
```

and `FactTest` looks like this:

```
test_date       Download      LocationName
1/4/2020        8.56          Houston
1/4/2020        9.43          Dallas
1/5/2020        3.20          Houston
```

When I'm creating the `cube` in `VS 2013`, I notice that the column `LocationName` is not included as one of the `Measures`. I also have other Dimension tables, and none of the *primary key* columns are part of the Measures.
[image]

Aren't the primary keys supposed to be used as `Measures` when creating a `cube`? If not, then how am I supposed to link the fact tables to the dim tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is caused by incorrect PK definition in DimLocation.
All dimensions PK should be integers, so LocationId should be your PK and you should include it in the fact table instead of LocationName. Location Name should be defined as a dimension attribute.
In your cube the only measure is "[DOWNLOAD] [float]".

Definition of a Measure: It is any numeric quantity/value that represents a metric aligned to an organization's goals. Measures are stored in the fact table.

Comment: So how will I link `DimLocation.LocationName` to `FactSpeed.LocationName` if I remove the PK `DimLocation.LocationName`?

Comment: You should not have any varchar columns in fact tables. You ETL/ELT process should calculate LocationId for each row.

Comment: In other words, a fact table will be unreadable unless a join is made with the dim table?

Comment: Yes, that is kinda a point of dimensional modeling to minimize storage. You can look into newer technologies like columnsore or tabular cube, they solve this problem in a different way.

Comment: I made the changes, but I still can't see the measure. I've posted the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60232755/ssdt-not-seeing-measure-in-cube-wizard?noredirect=1#comment106540612_60232755) again.